# Cloning entities in a-frame

Tags: three.js, aframe

I am trying to create multiple clones of a gltf model in loop and distribute them

The original model is referred here -

```
<a-entity id="orca" position="4 0 -40" gltf-model="#orca1" static-body animation="property: position.y; dir: alternate; dur: 1000; easing: easeInSine; loop: true; to: 0.5 "></a-entity>
```

and I am trying to create multiple copies in a component called model-subset -

```
<a-entity model-subset="target: #orca; name: ORCA3DS;"></a-entity>
```

The component code is as follows -

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-subset', {
  schema: {
    target: { default: '', type: 'selector' },
    name: { default: '' }
  },
  init: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    var data = this.data;
    data.target.addEventListener('model-loaded', function(e){
    var model = e.detail.model;
    var subset = model.getObjectByName(data.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var clone = subset.clone();
      clone.visible = true;
      clone.position.x += Math.random() * 5;
      clone.position.y += 0.5;
      clone.position.z = -20 + Math.random() * 20;
      el.setObject3D('clone', clone);   
   });    
  }  
});
```

However, only one clone gets created instead of ten. Is it that I need to listen for some event before I can iterate in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I was attaching all the objects to the same entity. Each object needs its own entity. Modified the component code to following to get it to work -

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-subset', {
  schema: {
    target: { default: '', type: 'selector' },
    name: { default: '' }
  },
  init: function() {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
    var data = this.data;
    data.target.addEventListener('model-loaded', function(e){
    var model = e.detail.model;
    var subset = model.getObjectByName(data.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var clone = subset.clone();
      var entity = document.createElement('a-entity');
      sceneEl.appendChild(entity);          
      clone.visible = true;
      clone.position.x += Math.random() * 5;
      clone.position.y += 0.5;
      clone.position.z = -20 + Math.random() * 20;
      entity.setObject3D('clone', clone);   
   });    
  }  
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, can add the clone directly to the three.js scene graph if you don't need them as entities `var container = new THREE.Object3D(); entity.setObject3D('container', container); container.add(clone)`.

Comment: thanks @ngokevin is it better to do it this way from performance point of view?

Comment: yeah, you avoid a bunch of asynchrony and initialization code, but definitely do it the aframe way if you have other aframe logic you need to attach beyond just plopping in models